# Piping `find` to 'tail`

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I want to get the last two lines of the find output and copy them somewhere. I tried

```
find . -iname "*FooBar*" | tail -2 -exec cp "{}" dest \;
```

but the output was "invalid option --2" for tail.

Also, my file or directory name contains spaces.

Comment: @Gabe. *output*, I think. It's not an abbreviation I've ever seen before. I've edited it out now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work on absolutely any paths.

Declare a function to be able to [use `head` and `tail` on NUL-separated output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75206/3645):

```
nul_terminated() {
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | "$@" | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'
}
```

Then you can use it to get a NUL-separated list of paths from your search after passing through `tail`:

```
find . -exec printf '%s\0' {} \; | nul_terminated tail -n 2
```

You can then pipe that to `xargs` and add your options:

```
find . -iname "*FooBar*" -exec printf '%s\0' {} \; | nul_terminated tail -n 2 | xargs -I "{}" -0 cp "{}" "dest"
```

Explanation:

1. `find` files in the current directory (`.`) and below with a name    containing `foobar` (case insensitive because of the `i` in    `-iname`);
2. for each file, run (`-exec`) a command to
3. print each file path (`{}`) followed by a NUL character (`\0`) individually (`\;`);
4. swap newlines and NUL characters (`tr '\0\n' '\n\0'`);"
5. get the last two lines (that is, paths; `tail -n 2`, `"$@"`);
6. swap newlines and NUL characters again to get a NUL-separated list of file names (`tr '\0\n' '\n\0'`).

The `xargs` command is a bit harder to explain. It builds as many `cp ... "dest"` commands as necessary to fit in the *maximum command length* of the operating system, replacing the `{}` token in the command with the actual file name (`-I "{}" ... "{}"`), using the NUL character as a separator when reading the parameters (`-0`).

Comment: wonderful!! I never thought of doing such thing, thanks and 1up

Comment: Please forgive me if it's a dumb question, but shouldn't we use the flag `-I` (ie: `xargs -I "{}" -0 cp "{}" "dest"`)? (When I try without it doesn't seem to work. eg: `echo "abc" | xargs echo "{}" def` prints `{} def abc`)

Comment: @gturri I think you're right. I'm not that used to `xargs` since I usually process file names with `while IFS= read -r -d '' ...`

Comment: @l0b0 That worked perfectly. Thanks. But please forgive me for asking, can you please explain in detail what you did above?

Comment: @l0b0 last question, what is "$@"?

Comment: That is a way to print every parameter properly quoted, separated by spaces. It preserves special characters in parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
cp $(find . -iname "*FooBar*" | tail -2 ) dest
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -iname "*FooBar*"|tail -n2|xargs -i cp "{}" dest
```

Unfortunately this won't work with filenames that contain spaces or newlines.

Comment: in my case there are spaces in filenames

Answer (score 2):

Robin Green:

> `$ find . -iname "*FooBar*"|tail -n2|xargs -i cp "{}" dest`
>   [Unfortunately this won't work with filenames that contain spaces or newlines.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20936257/368630)

This will work (at least to the `tail`) if the file contains spaces. That's because the find will put each file on one line including spaces, tabs, and other special characters.

The problem is that `xargs` will not operate with spaces. You can use the `-0` or `--null` option with `xargs`, but that was designed with `find ... -print0` in mind.

What might work is using a `while` loop.

```
find . -iname "*FooBar*" | tail -n2 | while read file
do
   cp "$file" "$dest"
done
```

Since you're only reading in one item per line, the `$file` will contain the file name with all of the various characters. The only time this will not work is if `$file` contains a NL. Then, the `tail` command itself will have issues. Fortunately, having a NL in a file name is quite rare.

Some people do this:

```
while IFS=\n read file
```

which removes input separators on anything other than a NL, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since You file contains 2 lines also have spaces lets keep inverted commas

```
while read line
do

 cp "$line" dest;

done < $(find . -iname "*FooBar*" | tail -2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
find . -iname "filename" -exec tail -n 2 {} \; > output.txt
```